# Big square wordpress post thumbnails

Tags: php, wordpress

Does anybody know how to get square wordpress thumbnails?

If I use this the images aren't square

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( array(205,205) ); ?>
```

But if I do this, they are square

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( array(135,135) ); ?>
```

I need to create a thumbnail gallery with let s say 300 x 300 square images.

Comment: "If I use this the images aren't square" - what do you mean with "this"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create your own picture size first. This is done with the [add_image_size()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) function.

You can do it like this:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size( 'square-large', 300, 300, true); // name, width, height, crop 
    add_filter('image_size_names_choose', 'my_image_sizes');
}

function my_image_sizes($sizes) {
    $addsizes = array(
        "square-large" => __( "Large square image")
    );
    $newsizes = array_merge($sizes, $addsizes);
    return $newsizes;
}
```

This will add the support for thumbnails to your theme if it hasn't it already. It will create a new image size with cropped 300x300 pixels. The second function gives it a nicer description and makes sure it will show up in the media insert dialogs.

Then you can use it like this.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'square-large' ); ?>
```

You can add these lines in the `functions.php` of your theme. If you want to make sure that these lines aren't overwritten when the theme gets updated I strongly suggest to create a child theme, you can [read here how to do that](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

This will not affect existing images. You can recreate the missing thumbnails with this code:

```
include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';
function regenerate_all_attachment_sizes() {
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => 100, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => null, 'post_mime_type' => 'image' ); 
    $attachments = get_posts( $args );
    if ($attachments) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $post ) {
            $file = get_attached_file( $post->ID );
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $post->ID, wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $post->ID, $file ) );
        }
    }       
}
regenerate_all_attachment_sizes();
```

This only has to be run once.

Comment: So let me get this right. When uploading an image, the add_image_size will create a 300x300 thumbnail which I can later use. But how do I use it? Like this? `<?php the_post_thumbnail( array(300,300) ); ?>`

Comment: How do I run that code for recreating thumbnails? I pasted it in functions.php and got a Server error.

Comment: Check the error logs of your server for the cause. I copied these lines straight out of my `functions.php`.

Comment: I will. Thank you for your help. I got something going here. It's better than what I had before.