# Define a new cropping image size in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, crop

Inside Wordpress, I need to generate and create inside the upload folder a new cropping image size that has:

- width=205px
- height=120px

Inside my function.php here is my code:

```
// Call function on after setup
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup_img' );
function theme_setup_img() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size('search-thumb', 205, 120, true );
    // set_post_thumbnail_size( 205, 120, true );
}
```

However, no new image-sizes have been created inside the upload folder (only default WP sizes). Any solution?

Note: I'm using the default theme and the latest WP version

Comment: This will only apply to new uploads. If you want to resize existing images as well you need to write a function that iterates through all of them and rewrites the images. See my answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14643131/212107).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Big square wordpress post thumbnails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642567/big-square-wordpress-post-thumbnails)

Comment: Even to new uploads, the new image size isn't generated. To let you know, My images is 2000px by 1500px so the crop should work. I tried without any plug-in installed, still the same issue...
Could it be the php version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was the "Dynamic Image Resizer" plug-in.
It was breaking my theme with Wordpress 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks correct. Mine is slightly different and I know it works:

```
if (function_exists('add_theme_support'))
{
  // Add Thumbnail Theme Support
  add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
  add_image_size('large', 700, '', true); // Large Thumbnail
  add_image_size('medium', 250, '', true); // Medium Thumbnail
}
```

This was taken from the [HTML5 Blank Theme](https://github.com/toddmotto/html5blank) by Todd Motto. Gerald also mentioned writing a script to re-render but there's a great plugin for that called [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) that does the same thing.

Comment: Even with your code, I'm not creating new images inside the upload folder

Comment: It was a plug-in issue

Answer (score 2):

This might be due to you calling the new size inside the "after_setup_theme" action... I use the following code:

```
// Add custom image sizes
if( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'search-thumb', 205, 120, true );
}
```

And it works every time... if it's inside the functions.php file, you don't need an action or hook to make it work.

Also, you can add this to functions.php to make your custom sizes show up in the drop down menus when inserting images into pages/posts/where ever:

```
// Functions to add custom image sizes to the media library thickbox area
// and put them into drop down
function my_insert_custom_image_sizes( $sizes ) {
    // get the custom image sizes
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
    // if there are none, just return the built-in sizes
    if ( empty( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) )
        return $sizes;
    // add all the custom sizes to the built-in sizes
    foreach ( $_wp_additional_image_sizes as $id => $data ) {
        // take the size ID (e.g., 'my-name'), replace hyphens with spaces,
        // and capitalise the first letter of each word
        if ( !isset($sizes[$id]) )
            $sizes[$id] = ucfirst( str_replace( '-', ' ', $id ) );
    }
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_insert_custom_image_sizes' );
```

You will need a plugin (I use [AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/)) to resize old images already uploaded before this code was implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. To let you know, hooks are usefull used outside the function.php.